# OpenId Connect JWT sub or email

Tags: google-signin, openid-connect, google-openid, google-account, googlesigninaccount

I'm very new to about OpenID Connect Authentication!
(also OAuth2.0 too..)

Anyway my question is,

"What is the necessary user-data things of the JWT?"
("sub" or "user-email"?)

And what is real mean as google sign in saying? 
I think, we can not change Google account's email, isn't it?

Note: A Google account's email address can change, so don't use it to identify a user. Instead, use the account's ID, which you can get on the client with getBasicProfile().getId(), and on the backend from the sub claim of the ID token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sub` claim is required in an `id_token`, `email` is optional, see: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken. As you mention e-mail addresses can change, `sub` should not change and when combined with the `iss` claim that represents the Provider - Google in your case - it can be used to obtain a globally unique user identifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

And I have some question, id_token also has "exp" (Expiration time) so,,
In RP, if exp time is over, do I get new valid id_token also?

I have some confusing about expiration time and like a reflash access token..

Comment: the `exp` says when the token itself becomes invalid, after which it should no longer be accepted by a recipient; it doesn't necessarily relate the the session that the RP started when it received the `id_token` initially